# How can I only return words that contain specified letters?

Tags: python

The title ^. For some reason the code I have now is allowing words to slip through that evidently don't contain the required letters.

```
listOfValid = ["xxxxy", "xxxxz", "xxxxx", "a", "ab"]
lettersIn = ["a", "b"]

for word in listOfValid:
    for letter in lettersIn:
        if letter not in word and word in listOfValid:
            listOfValid.remove(word)

print(listOfValid)
```

This returns: 'xxxxz' 'a' 'ab'. Why is it allowing xxxxz and a through?

Comment: Why are you checking `and word in listOfValid:` ? you take `word`from this list!

Comment: Why do you iterate a list and modify it. That is a big NO-NO.

Comment: That might be because you're modifying the list that you're iterating through. Try creating a new empty list and use `append` to add values to the new list. Also you'll have to change your condition to the opposite (`letter in word`)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you wanted to do this?

```python
listOfValid = ["xxxxy", "xxxxz", "xxxxx", "a", "ab"]
lettersIn = ["a", "b"]

for word in listOfValid[:]:
    for letter in lettersIn:
        if letter in word:
            break
    else:
        listOfValid.remove(word)

print(listOfValid)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsMgEETvfsXiKYHSSy8l0A/oqbdeQg6GrFRqVTaSJv15mzWEOAcZ5jmzYYkv7y7XQClZM8aHfiprBrhBK@dVizxBNr/dzGxUfnrZCYsxIo13lys551hoT/D1NIBxUAy3TdcIWMV86@Yf@8oGWUYXnJcOxOoJ1TsnaEc8WHHrTPjxE1ZcroUIZFysCl6n9Ac)

You can't iterate on an array that you are modifying, so `listOfValid[:]` copies the array.

Although you should probably do something more like this:

```python
listOfValid = ["xxxxy", "xxxxz", "xxxxx", "a", "ab"]
lettersIn = ["a", "b"]

listOfValid = [*filter(lambda i:any(map(lambda l:l in i,lettersIn)),listOfValid)]

print(listOfValid)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyezuMQ/LSwxJzNFwVYhWqkCCCqVdBTAjCoYowLESAQTSUqxXDmpJSWpRcWeeWAtYHGQMBeaYVppmTlAdRo5iblJKYkKmVaJeZUauYkFMIEcqxyFzDyFTB24eZqaOkhmaAKNLCjKzCvRQBb8/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

Using list compreenssion this should work:

```
[x for x in listOfValid if x in lettersIn]
```